# Estimate the volume of a convex body given a uniform random sample of points inside it?

Tags: convex-analysis, monte-carlo

Let $K$ be a convex, full-dimensional, bounded region of $\mathbb{R}^n$. More precisely, there exist two balls of radiuses $0<r<R$ such that the ball of radius $r$ is fully contained inside $K$ and the ball of radius $R$ fully contains $K$.

Now suppose that for any positive integer $N$, I have a black-box that generates $N$ independent random points which are uniformly distributed inside $K$. Given this black-box, what's an efficient algorithm to estimate the volume of $K$?

By efficient algorithm, I mean minimize $N$, the size of the sample of points, to obtain a desired standard error in the volume estimate.

**Note:** You can assume that $r,R$ and the centers of the corresponding balls are known.

Comment: Presumably "independently uniformly distributed" is implied?

Comment: @joriki Of course.

Comment: This is in a sense a multidimensional version of the [German tank problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem). You can view $K$ as the unknown parameter of the distribution. I don't see an obvious natural/uninformative prior or class of priors for $K$. But perhaps it's possible to forget about $K$ and try to look only at its volume, for which a similar trick as in the German tank problem might be able to solve the improper prior problem. In any case, I think "what's an efficient algorithm" is the second step; first you need to find a meaningful estimator for the volume of $K$.

Comment: When you write "a desired standard error", do you mean this in the [minimum-variance unbiased estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-variance_unbiased_estimator) sense? That is, do you want to minimize $N$ (or equivalently the variance) simultaneously for all possible $K$? (If not, you'd need to specify a distribution for $K$ with respect to which the minimum is defined.)

Comment: @joriki Agree. A first step would be any algorithm, efficient or not. By "a desired standard error", I mean that the estimated $K$ should be reported as $K \pm E$, where $E$ is an estimate of the error. Given $E$, an efficient algorithm should estimate $K$ without using too many sample points. What I am trying to say is that my measure of efficiency is $N$. But of course, a practical algorithm doesn't have to minimize $N$!

Comment: @About your previous comment: It's not clear to me how this estimate of the error is meant to be defined. If you want a single estimate of the error, you're again going to need a prior distribution for $K$ with which to weight the errors? Or are you expecting the error to be independent of $K$?

Comment: OK -- with the balls and their radii now known, it might make sense to assume a flat prior for the volume of $K$ in the interval between the volumes of the balls.

Comment: @joriki I agree that a prior distribution for $K$ is needed in principle, but I have no idea how to define one. I guess that is part of the question. And I agree with you. I am *not* giving a precise definition of the error, because I don't know how to do it. But intuitively I expect that given the points, one can produce an estimate of the volume. Finding a rigorous way to do it is the essence of the question.

Comment: I see. Perhaps you could try to make that a bit clearer in the question. With the balls and their radii now known, it might make sense to assume a flat prior for the volume of $K$ in the interval between the volumes of the balls -- which of course doesn't yield a prior for $K$ (which in any case is a problematic concept since $K$ is an arbitrary convex body that can't be specified by countably many parameters), but since you're only interested in the volume, it might be possible to abstract from $K$.